# Переключение раскладки в KDE 5.8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

Установил KDE 5.8.6 на Ubuntu 16.04 (параллельно с Unity).
Стандартная иконка с языками в трее отображала настройки какого-то IBus и в упор не хотела понимать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
Залез в Параметры Системы → Устройства ввода → Клавиатура → Раскладки, там добавил раскладку и включил <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, иконка в трее сменилась, IBus куда-то пропал.

В обычных приложениях (Chrome, Telegram, Thunderbird и т.п.) всё прекрасно работает — языки переключаются, текст печатается.

А вот в интерфейсе KDE текст не печатается, я не могу ввести текст в поиске в "Меню запуска приложений", в поиске по <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, ввести пароль при обновлении приложений и т.д. Иногда могут проскользнуть буквы, т.е. нажимаешь <kbd>s</kbd> — появляется `s`, но вторую ты уже не можешь ввести.
Как настроить нормально переключение клавиатуры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нашел решение https://askubuntu.com/questions/838613/keyboard-not-working-properly-in-kde-after-upgrade-to-kubuntu-16-10

```
sudo apt purge ibus
sudo apt install fcitx
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fcitx
sudo reboot
```